# Stepping through countdowns, unsure how to do this

Tags: php

I have a somewhat working countdown script already with a defined time (using new DateTime) but haven't figured out how to automatically swap times daily.

I'm looking to do a countdown every day at 5:10, 5:50, and 6:15 PM UTC. If 5:10:00 passes, then swap the countdown for 5:50:00. If it's 6:16, then it'll show for 5:10 tomorrow

How would I be doing comparisons for this? It says something about a non-object when I try to just use the datetime'd variable in a > <

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than comparing the objects themselves, you can compare their timestamps. For example:

```php
if($dateTime1->getTimestamp() > $dateTime2->getTimestamp()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to assign something like `if [past 17:10:00] { $countdown = [today 17:50:00] }`? Maybe using the word assignments like +1 day or tomorrow or something? Still somewhat unsure about it

Comment: @jmoon: You should just be able to compare the current time to a given time. So for `if [past 17:10:00]` you might have `$now = new DateTime('now'); $someTime = new DateTime("17:10:00"); if($someTime->getTimestamp() > $now->getTimestamp())`